# Migrate / Archive inactive data from Postgres to S3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration

We have a Postgres table with `tenants` and multiple foreign key tables with `tenant_id`. We would like to archive all the data to an s3 bucket and deleted from the Postgres table whenever a `tenant` is set to inactive (`is_active = false`) in order to save on storage costs.

I'm wondering what is the best way to do this? I was looking at Database Migration Services but it seems like that would replicate all of the data not just the inactive data. I would also need to just delete the inactive data afterwards not the entire table. I also thought to identify all the tables that need to migrate data and run a script to save the data to an s3 bucket and then delete the data from the source tables if I was able to successfully replicate the data into S3.

Are there any other methods to accomplish this easily? There are quite a bit of tables connected to a `tenant` and I want to make sure there isn't an easier way to migrate the inactive data than writing a long script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Create a **Snapshot** of the database, which contains a *complete copy* of the database. Then, delete the data from the database. If the data is needed in future, you can **Restore the Snapshot** to a new database and recover the data. You will be charged for storing the snapshot. *OR*
- **Export the data**, then delete the data. It won't be easy to 'restore' the data into the database in future, but at least you will have a copy of it in S3.

You can [Export data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html) by using the `aws_s3` extension. It takes an SQL statement (eg `select * from table where tenant_id = 12`) and a bucket and key for where to store the data. It is saved in CSV format (but `options` can modify things like delimiters).

So, just run the export command for all tables and rows that you want to keep.